# Access denied (#1227) when uploading sql.qz to site

Tags: mysql, file-upload, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to upload a `sql.qz` file onto `phpmyadmin` and I keep getting this error. I created a site offline using `Xampp` and now when I was to upload it it's not letting me. I have all privileges and my host even verified with me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Error

SQL query: Documentation

--
-- Database: `wordpress`
--
DELIMITER $$--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_multi_sets` ( )
    DETERMINISTIC BEGIN SELECT user( ) AS first_col;

SELECT user( ) AS first_col, now( ) AS second_col;

SELECT user( ) AS first_col, now( ) AS second_col, now( ) AS third_col;

end$$
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `DEFINER` from your query. I believe that is what's causing the error. Definer is not mandatory and is a privileged operation. You can see more about it here [Create Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

So your statements in your backup can look like this and it should work fine.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_multi_sets` ( )...
```